# Excel opens up VBA editor opens up during processing. No error generated

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote an application in Excel VBA, when it gets to this function, it **sometimes** and ***only*** sometimes stops, opens up the editor and highlights the last line before "end Function"

```
Option Explicit

Function Get_Special(i_Row, c_Total, v_code As Variant) As Currency

Dim c_money As Currency
Dim s_Code As String
Dim i_Ctr As Integer

c_money = 0

If Not IsArrayInitialized(v_code) Then
    Get_Special = c_money + c_Total
    Exit Function
End If

For i_Ctr = LBound(v_code) To UBound(v_code)
    Select Case v_code(i_Ctr)

        Case 1 To 10

        Case 11  
             If c_Total = 0 Then c_money = Minimum_Charge(i_Row)
        Case 12  
            c_money = c_money + Plug_Fee(i_Row, Range(rngName(RNM.PLUG)).Column) 
        Case Else

    End Select
Next i_Ctr
'VBA editor opens here, highlighted.  No error message is given pressing F5 causes it to finish with no problem.  

Get_Special = c_money  
End Function
```

I am at a loss

To address the questions below:

The IsArrayInitialized function has "On Error resume next" error handling, which then checks to see if the error number is zero, if not, the function returns false.

The error is intermittent.  I ran the code 70 times with different data entered each time and could not recreate the error a second time.

I double checked and there is no break point set.

Comment: You have nothing for `Case 1 To 10`?

Comment: Nothing, no error at all, the editor just pops up with no message and the line Get_Special = c_money   highlighted.  and it doesn't do it all the time

Comment: Case 1 to 10 may have something in the future, and it originally did.  End users are getting the error and I was able to recreate it once, but only once.

Comment: Uh can you have empty cases? What has debugging revealed so far? And are you calling other functions?

Comment: @findwindow yes you can have empty cases, it does nothing.

Comment: What option do you have selected in "Error Trapping" in the VBE options?

Comment: In `IsArrayInitialized`, do you have `On Error Resume Next` with no `On Error GoTo 0`?

Comment: Unlikely but I will ask just in case. Is there a break point set on that line i.e. a brown dot in the margin next to that line as its easy to set accidentally. Your exit function would mean it does not always get that far which is why it could be sometimes..

Comment: I am calling three functions to this one, IsArrayInitialized, which is a function that attempts to get the lower bound of an array, and returns false if an error is generated.  The other two are lookups of charges under special circumstances.  11 and 12 are special cases flagged in a column on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Debug -> Clear all Debug Points.
Debug -> Compile. Then save the file. Sometimes phantom debug break points exist.

Comment: @CodyG. That seems to have fixed it!  Thanks.  Why don't you put your comment down as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @RichardU Done! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug -> Clear all Debug Points. 
Debug -> Compile. Then save the file. 
Sometimes phantom debug break points exist.